# I have used wikitude sdk for AR.Now how can i create compass for finding my object.?

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude-sdk

I have used wikitude sdk for Augmented Reality.Now I want to find my object is where it is perfect located, Like i want to integrate a small compass as sub-module of my AR.

Thanks in Advance.